# C request for member ***** in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, list, pointers, singly-linked-list

I know there are some posts just like this one, but all solutions on those posts didn't help me, and they tended to just say switching l.valor to l->valor, and that is not working in my case, and I don't understand why.

This is what I have:

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;

void insertOrd (LInt *g, int x){
    if (g != NULL) g->valor = x;
}
```

And I am getting this:

```
error: request for member 'valor' in something not a structure or union if (g == NULL) g->valor = x;
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: This is an exercise on a platform called codeboard, it is homework, I can't change the struct declaration, nor can I change the arguments of the function insertOrd, I have to use what I get on insertOrd and make the function work

Comment: 1) `l` is pointer to pointer of `struct lligada`

Comment: `l` is too easily confused with `1` in a monospaced font, and is the worst possible use of the single-letter variable. And the names of function arguments should *help* the user not hinder them.

Comment: I've changed it to avoid confusion but it wasn't set by me, I just have to complete it.

Comment: `(*g)->valor` etc.  Pointers hidden in `typedefs` are confusing if you need to apply a dereference operation to it.

Comment: [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have to write

```
void insertOrd (LInt *g, int x){
    if (*g != NULL) ( *g )->valor = x;
        ^^ ^^         ^^^
}
```

or

```
void insertOrd (LInt g, int x){
                ^^^^^^
    if (g != NULL) g->valor = x;
          ^^
}
```

because the type of the parameter `g` in the presented function is `struct lligada **`

Comment: I think this worked, but I have a problem with something else, how do I check if the LInt *g I receive as an argument is empty? I am supposed to make (*g)->valor = x if it is empty, but doing if((*g)==NULL) is giving me segmentation fault

Comment: @NepsName `if (g != NULL && *g != NULL)`

Comment: @NepsName I wrote in the answer that you have to check if ( *g != NULL ) instead of if ( *g == NULL )

Answer (score 4):

Remove the * from the struct declaration:

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} LInt;
```

By the way you're NULL check is inversed. It should probably read `if (l != NULL)`.

Comment: Ok, I should probably have said this already. This is an exercise on a platform called codeboard, it is homework, I can't change the struct declaration, nor can I change the arguments of the function insertOrd, I have to use what I get on insertOrd and make the function work

Comment: @NepsName you can do whatever you like in your preparation of the homework, before you get to its requirement.